# how to check whether get or post method is called

Tags: html, servlets

html form does not include which method (GET OR POST) should be called after particular action. how to identify that in a servlet whether the request is for get or post

Answer (score 0):

1. Use F12 to see the console in your internet explorer.
2. See the server log in your app server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up Google Chrome
2. Go to your site
3. Right click on the web page and tap on Inspect Element
4. Tap on the "Network" tap and you can see what methods are being called

Tip - You might have to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

submit the action, check the url info, if the url contains parameters, the method is 'get'; otherwise the method is post. 
eg. 
when log in with name 'name' and pwd '123123'
Get: http://**.**.com/actionName?name=name&pwd=123123
Post: http://**.**.com/actionName

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specify the method attribute in your html form,the servlet container takes your request as GET.see[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)
If you are not specify the methods attribute,the doGet()method is called.if you put post in your method attribute doPost() method is called.